# Can NetBeans use Open JDK?

Tags: netbeans

I've been using NetBeans for a long time at both work and home but now I face a licensing issue. We're forbidden to use JDK in the whole company.

Did anyone have any luck with trying to use Open JDK instead? The documentation for the newest version (19) doesn't seem to give you that option.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans with Adoptium Temurin (https://adoptium.net/) which is based on OpenJDK without any problems

Comment: Yes, seems to be working with Adoptium. Haven't tested all function, but so far, so good. Many thanks.